# Delete duplictes from large MySQL table which contains 1 billion records based on certain columns values

Tags: mysql

I have a table detail and that table contains 1 billion records till today.

```
CREATE TABLE `detail` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `EINNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Form` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionStatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionStatusNo` int NOT NULL,
 
  `StatusDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 
  `UniqueFormId` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionFacility` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  
  `StatusDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EINNo` (`EINNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EmployeeNo` (`EmployeeNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_Form` (`Form`),
  KEY `idx_detail_UniqueFormId` (`UniqueFormId`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionFacility` (`ProductionFacility`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionStatusNo` (`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_StatusDate` (`StatusDate`),
  KEY `idx_covering_detail_all` (`StatusDate`,`ProductionStatusNo`,`ProductionFacility`(30),`UniqueFormId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7974559 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
```

I want to delete duplicate records from that table based on UniqueFormId,ProductionStatusNo, ProductionStatus, StatusDate and ProducitonFacility . I want to keep the oldest record which have the Min Id for that UniqueFormIndex.

as this table contains so many records I need batch deletion.

so far what I tried as follow :

```
DELETE d1
FROM detail d1
JOIN detail d2 ON 
  d1.UniqueFormId = d2.UniqueFormId AND
  d1.ProductionStatusNo = d2.ProductionStatusNo AND
  d1.ProductionStatus = d2.ProductionStatus AND
  d1.StatusDate = d2.StatusDate AND
  d1.ProductionFacility = d2.ProductionFacility AND
  d1.Id > d2.Id
LIMIT 1000;
```

based on comment recommendation :

```
 START TRANSACTION;
    
    
    CREATE TABLE temp_detail AS
    SELECT *
    FROM detail
    WHERE (UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo, ProductionStatus, StatusDate, ProductionFacility, Id) IN (
        SELECT UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo, ProductionStatus, StatusDate, ProductionFacility, MIN(Id) AS MinId
        FROM detail
        GROUP BY UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo, ProductionStatus, StatusDate, ProductionFacility
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    );
    
    
    DROP TABLE detail;
    
    
    ALTER TABLE temp_detail RENAME TO detail;
    
    
    COMMIT;
```

here is another update based on suggestion from comments , using  `ROW_NUMBER()` as I am using MySQL 8.0.25 version instead of using `SELECT WHERE IN`

```
START TRANSACTION;
    
CREATE TABLE temp_detail AS
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        d.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo, ProductionStatus, StatusDate, ProductionFacility ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM detail d
) AS ranked
WHERE RowNum = 1;
    
    
DROP TABLE detail;
    
    
ALTER TABLE temp_detail RENAME TO detail;
    
    
 COMMIT;
```

Comment: Now the table contains ~1kkk rows. What is approximate amount of the rows to be saved?

Comment: Recommendation: select the rows to be saved to temptable, truncate your table, copy saved rows back. Or, if there is no foreign keys on this table - copy rows, drop this table and rename temptable.

Comment: that is total rows right now  and after deletion rows will be around 80M only approx.

Comment: I so then my recommendation may improve the process dramatically. The only thing which must be taken into account - you must prevent the access to the table during the clearing process.

Comment: I made edit in question , can you please confirm is that what you are suggesting , I just added transction also in the script.  this code need to be run on produciton so I just want to make sure its completed or at least have option to roll back. thanks

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: MySQL version  8.0.25

Comment: If so then use not SELECT WHERE IN but ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: PS. Transaction makes no sense - any DDL commits current transaction.

Comment: Your last code with ROW_NUMBER have an unaccuracy - it adds `RowNum` column into table structure. Replace an asterisk with definite columns list. And I'd recommend you to create empty table with CREATE TABLE AS then copy rows into it with INSERT. Also use not transaction but LOCK TABLES.

Comment: I dont want that RowNum in my main table but I cant remove it and also I need where RowNum=1 and that also not working , its throwing error